# GDB 7.7 symbols error SHT_SYMTAB_SHNDX

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, elf

We have upgraded our C compiler to 4.5.3 and are now experiencing problems when trying to debug the server binary on solaris (works fine on linux rhel5 and AIX 6.1)

Below is the log of a debugging attempt. Any help would be appreciated.

```
-bash-3.00$ gdb myServer
Python Exception exceptions.ImportError No module named gdb:

warning:
Could not load the Python gdb module from `/usr/local/share/gdb/python'.
Limited Python support is available from the _gdb module.
Suggest passing --data-directory=/path/to/gdb/data-directory.

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "sparc-sun-solaris2.10".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
BFD: BFD (GNU Binutils) 2.24.51.20140206 assertion fail elf.c:1727
Reading symbols from myServer...BFD: /data3/develop/myServer symbol number 7 references nonexistent SHT_SYMTAB_SHNDX section
Can't read symbols from /data3/develop/myServer: Invalid operation
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

> BFD: BFD (GNU Binutils) 2.24.51.20140206 assertion fail elf.c:1727

This is a bug in gnu binutils. You should report it [here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=binutils).